# JetBrains Intellij missing javax.validation

Tags: java, bean-validation

I've just created a project from an existing netbeans project, and I've gotten an error in one import

[image]

Any way to fix this?

Comment: This is not the JPA API. It is the Bean Validation API. As per http://beanvalidation.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `javax.validation.*` classes exist in a third party library. You have to import it.

Add the corresponding jar to the classpath or add this to your `pom.xml` if you are using maven :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I've no knowledge if the intellj have the same possibilities as netbeans in imports of jar's.. I'll check that out. Thanks for quick answer

Comment: @ChristianMoen The recommended way is to use maven (or Gradle). Manually importing jars is painful when working with colleagues.

Comment: Sorry, if I ask much.. Never been using Maven.. Is it possible to include Maven even if I've started coding?

Comment: @ChristianMoen It will require to replace manually imported jars with the equivalent declarations in `pom.xml`. That should be easy if the project is small. I recommend to try on a new project first, understand how it works then adapt your existing project. Note : IntelliJ has a powerful built-in Maven support. Try `File -> new -> Project...` then select `Maven`.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue but with Non-maven Project,

this validation Jar need to be manually added.

and can be downloaded using some Online Maven download tool like

https://jar-download.com/online-maven-download-tool.php

and then add as project library in the project.

Other wise just use maven as mentioned above by @Arnaud Denoyelle